# Maven does not compile other classes into a jar after compiling and packaging

Tags: java, maven

I structured my code into different classes, but maven somehow doesn't recognize the other classes than MainClass when I tried to compile and package it.

[image]

This is the error I've received.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/UnhandledAlertException
    at MainClass.<init>(MainClass.java:8)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

My code was trying to access a function from SeleniumController but somehow maven doesn't recognize the class thus returning the error from above.

I already tried using:

```
mvn compile
mvn clean install
mvn package
```

Here is my pom.xml

https://pastebin.com/NKd6x7jY

Comment: What's missing are not _your_ other classes but the selenium classes, i.e. the selenium dependencies. What does your pom.xml look like? Also, I'd recommend using a package for your classes as well as that will remove a potential source for bugs (some plugins etc. might expect a package since that's commonly the case for any non-trivial Java application)

Comment: I already have my selenium dependencies in my pom.xml. I think the error is referring to my other created class (SeleniumController). Which maven doesn't recognize.